# rxjs Observable.if always executes both statements when using map

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to decide which observable to return but the method `getUserFromApi` is always executed.
The idea is that no local user is present the service gets the user from the api otherwise it should just return the existant user.

```
export class  UserTestService {

 private user: User;

 getUserFromApi(): Observable<User> {
    const user = new User('John', 'Do', 'test')
    return Observable.of(user);
  }

  getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    return Observable.if(() => this.user == null, this.getUserFromApi().map((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;

        return this.user;
      }),
      Observable.of(this.user));
  }

  deleteCurrentUser(): void {
   this.user = new User('', '', '');
  }
}
```

And here's how I execute it (in a jasmine test)

```
userTestService.deleteCurrentUser();
userTestService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
      expect(user.username).toEqual('');
      done();
    });
```

I assume that it is because `this.getUserFromApi` in `Observable.if` gets executed too early.
But why is that and how can I solve it?

Comment: I don't see where you call any method from `UserTestService`.

Comment: sorry, copy paste error, since the actual code usage is a bit more complicated, I just included the necessary parts. I fixed the calls.

Comment: Why you think it calls both Observables? The condition is true when you run it, so how do you know it invokes also the "then" statement?

Comment: the condition is false because this.user is set to an empty user by `deleteCurrentUser()`.

If I add `console.log(this.user == null);` it will display `false`

Comment: The source of your problem has nothing to do with observables. In this statement `return Observable.if(() => this.user == null, this.getUserFromApi().map((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;

        return this.user;
      }),
      Observable.of(this.user));`, `this.getUserFromApi()` will always execute immediately. That's how JavaScript code execution works.

Comment: `deleteCurrentUser` doesn't set anything to `false`, it in fact makes the condition false every time with `this.user = new User('', '', '');`

Comment: @marting
Yes, and that's why it shouldn't execute `this.getUserFromApi()`

Comment: @Arikael No, you're having a very fundamental misunderstanding of how JavaScript works. `this.getUserFromApi()` is called _even before `Observable.if` is called_. `Observable.if` does not have the power to call or not call `this.getUserFromApi()` because _it has already been called_.

Comment: I know that a method like that gets executed, but I thought any `map` function is only executed when you call `subscribe` and therefore `getUserFromApi` will be executed in `Observable.if`s context, so to speak.

rxjs sometimes still is a riddle to me

Comment: @JLRishe That's not the problem he's having. The method returns Observable which does nothing until you subscribe to it.

Comment: @martin If that is the case, that's not the problem s/he described and s/he needs to describe the problem better. _"I'm trying to decide which observable to return but the method getUserFromApi is always executed."_.

Comment: @Arikael Are you saying (1) That `this.getUserFromApi()` is being called when you think it shouldn't, or (2) That the function in your `map` is being called when you think it shouldn't? Those are two very different things.

Comment: @Arikael Also, please explain how you are observing the issue. You say, _"I'm trying to decide which observable to return but the method getUserFromApi is always executed."_. How do you know that it is? Did you put a `console.log()` in it that you haven't shown us?

Comment: wow, I feel stupid now. The error is so obvious as many people already pointed out.
`this.getUserFromApi()` is called synchroniously/immediatly and so is the first line where I assign a new user. the rest of the function is async and I only tested if the function was called.

thanks for the help. @JLRishe if you add your comments as solution I'll accept them since they lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that by JavaScript execution rules, `this.getUserFromApi()` is called immediately (synchronously), so there is no way that `Observable.if` can exert any control over whether it is called or not:

```
return Observable.if(
    () => this.user == null, 
    this.getUserFromApi().map((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;

        return this.user;
    }),
    Observable.of(this.user));
```

The series of actions that take place when executing this statement are (in this order):

1. Evaluate `this.getUserFromApi()` which executes the body of that method. This evaluates to an observable because that method returns an observable.
2. Call `.map()` on that observable, which produces another observable.
3. Evaluate `this.user`, which produces the current value of `this.user`.
4. Evaluate `Observable.of()` on the value from step 3, which produces an observable.
5. Call `Observable.if()`, passing it the lambda function `() => this.user == null`, the observable from step 2, and the observable from step 4.

As we can see here, calling `this.getUserFromApi()` is the first thing that takes place, regardless of what `() => this.user == null` eventually evaluates to.

I believe that cartant's answer provides a way to ensure that `this.getUserFromApi()` is only called when the function in the first argument produces a `true` value, so I would recommend trying that out if you do indeed want to only call `this.getUserFromApi()` under that circumstance (which seems like a good idea).

Comment: I tried out the code in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntnzyb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) and it seems to work as Arikael expects. Sorry for missing an obvious point, what's happening here? (The 'test' is in app.component.ts constructor).

Comment: I should mention that StackBlitz never seems to run in it's preview pane, so you need to 'Open in a new window', then open the console.

Comment: @RichardMatsen When I view that StackBlitz, I see `Calling getUserFromApi()` in the console. Arikael was expecting `getUserFromApi()` to _not_ be called.

Comment: Yes, I just added the additional console log a second ago. I'm trying to work out the call chain. If the call originates in the code you cited above, why does it not wait until the Observable is subscribed as @martin suggests? Sorry, I'm feeling I'm missing the obvious, but would like to understand it.

Comment: I do see your point that the problem is **not** that the test is failing (which is the first impression).

Comment: @RichardMatsen You and Arikael are both getting bogged down in Observables when the matter at hand has nothing to do with them. Your question boils down to, "If I call a function, why does it not wait until the Observable is subscribed?" _Because you called it!_ Observe the list of steps I laid out above. The function is called in step 1, long before observables are even involved. And I'm pretty sure that martin understands this and that he thought OP was describing a different problem.

Comment: But the call to `getUserFromApi()` is inside the Observable.if(). The line you show only returns an observable object. It doesn't invoke it - something like returning a function does not invoke that function until the caller does so.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I don't know how much more clearly I can explain this. If you call `funcA(funcB(), funcC())`, the functions will be executed in the order `funcB`, `funcC`, `funcA`. `funcB` will not wait around until `funcA` decides   whether or not `funcB` should be called. `funcA` has no control over that. That is perfectly analogous to OP's code. `this.getUserFromApi()` is called _immediately_ and unconditionally. `Observable.if` has no control over whether or not it is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163350/discussion-between-richard-matsen-and-jlrishe).

Answer (score 3):

`getUserFromApi` is always going to execute, as it has to be called to obtain the observable that's passed as the second argument to `Observable.if`.

If you do not want `getUserFromApi` to execute until after the `if` expression is evaluated, you can use `defer`:

```js
getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
  return Observable.if(
    () => this.user == null,
    Observable.defer(() => this.getUserFromApi().map((user: User) => {
      this.user = user;
      return this.user;
    })),
    Observable.of(this.user)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@JLRishe is correct, the 2nd parameter to `Observable.if(..., this.getUserFromApi()..., ...` is invoked immediately in order to pass it in. (Took me ages to understand that. The observable mind-set!)

Wrapping the 2nd param with `Observable.defer` works, but you can also change the Observable.if for a ternary expression

```js
getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
  // return Observable.if(
  //   () => this.user == null,
  //   this.getUserFromApi().map((user: User) => {
  //     this.user = user;
  //     return this.user;
  //   }),
  //   Observable.of(this.user)
  // );
  return this.user == null
    ? this.getUserFromApi().map((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
        return this.user;
      })
    : Observable.of(this.user)
```

}

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhdmog?file=app%2Fuser.test.service.ts).

Note, the console.log() inside `getUserFromApi()` never gets called when the following sequence is excuted, because `deleteCurrentUser()` sets user to a default object.

```js
userTestService.deleteCurrentUser();
userTestService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
  expect(user.username).toEqual('');
  done();
  console.log('testing', user)
});
```

Comment: Good point. `Observable.if()` is overkill when all one wants to do is return the value of one expression or another from a function.